# C++ Array of struct initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, initialization

I am not really used to coding in C++ and this probably is a simple issue that I am not able to get the correct syntax of.

What I am basically trying to achieve is that, from one method where I declare an array of a struct (size not specified), I call a method where I pass this array. The method should initialize the values of the array. I tried to get a simple code working but getting errors. The following piece of code gives me a compilation error. Can someone point out how to achieve this?

```
struct ABC
{
int a;
int b;
};

void test(ABC * a)
{
a[] = {{2,3},{4,5}};
}

int main() {
    ABC arr[2];
    test(arr);
}
```

**EDIT:**
The following works, but I would like the initialization to work in one line.

```
struct ABC
{
int a;
int b;
};

void test(ABC *a)
{
a[0].a = 2;
a[0].b = 3;
a[1].a = 4;
a[1].b = 5;
}

int main() {
    ABC arr[2];
    test(arr);
}
```

Comment: If you have compilation errors, make sure you include the exact text of the messages.

Comment: Important bit to know about the array-pointer shuffle. Once that array is decayed to a pointer, it's a pointer. You've lost a piece of essential information: size.

Comment: To me it seems odd that you specify the size in the main loop, as you use this size in the test function.

Comment: Chiel, without specifying size, we cannot declare an array.

Comment: @sachin My point is that your test function also assumes that the array is of size two, even though it cannot know that. The function is therefore dangerous. Passing an ABC array of size 1 would trigger a segfault.

Comment: @Chiel, I agree to your point. I just posted this sample to see how the syntax works. Exception handling is a concern that I will tackle separately.

Comment: @sachin11 In my example you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Non-trivial, I'm afraid. An iniitializer list is intended to be used at initialization. You could initialize a temp array inside the function and then memcpy the temp into a, but that's ugly and dumb. Plus it's an almost certain fubar if you try it on a non-trivial object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a setup like this, making use of the C++ standard library. Compile it with the `-std=c++11` flag to allow for the initialization I did in the `push_back`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct ABC
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

void test(std::vector<ABC>& a)
{

    a.push_back({2,3});
    a.push_back({4,5});
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<ABC> arr;
    test(arr);

    // Test the outcome...
    std::cout << "The size is: " << arr.size() << std::endl;
    for (ABC& a : arr)
        std::cout << "Element (" << a.a << "," << a.b << ")" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Though this isn't using arrays as what my question asked, I actually like the simplicity of this answer :)

Comment: The way you use the array size discomforted me. You could also create a function that passed back an array if that is important to you?

Comment: @sachin11 about as often as not you will find that it's `vector` for the win in comparisons to arrays.

Comment: Agree to both of you on this. Haven't used vectors a great deal. Read about it now and really impressed by the power and flexibility it provides :) Will mark this as correct solution!

Comment: @sachin11 One small tweak: `a.insert(a.end(), {{2,3},{4,5}});`  Now you're back to your one-line solution.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize each struct accessing its index in `a` array.

```
void test(ABC * a)
{
    a[0] = {2,3};
    a[1] = {4,5};
    ...
```

This way `{{2,3},{4,5}};` will work on initialization, i.e

```
ABC arr[2] = {
    {2,3},
    {4,5}
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to first find out the actual size of the array and then iterate to initialize it.

**Will not work, see below**

```
void test(ABC* a) {        
    int value=2;
    for (int i=0;i++;i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(ABC)) {
        a[i].a=value;
        a[i].b=value+1;
        value+=2; } }
```

I am not 100% sure the sizeof(a) will work in giving you the size of the array. If that does not work you will have to pass the size of the array as a parameter:

```
void test(ABC* a, int elements) {        
    int value=2;
    for (int i=0;i++;i<elements) {
        a[i].a=value;
        a[i].b=value+1;
        value+=2; } }

int main() {
    ABC arr[2];
    test(arr,2); }
```

Comment: Why are you giving such an anti-advice?

Comment: Sergey, some are trying to help instead of posting snarky comments.

Comment: Help someone by drowning him?

Comment: If you absolutely need to 'discover' the size of the array and you don't want to pass it as a parameter like in my example above, look into this: http://www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/arrays/sizeof-array/

Comment: If you are using C++ and you need the size of the array, it makes a lot more sense to use a std container.

Comment: Sergey, if you have an actual REASON why my solution is wrong post it, otherwise stop trolling.

Comment: SunKnight0, without the size info passed, there is a chance of indexoutofbound exception. But if we ensure like in this simple code that we don't go out of bound, I guess size info should not be required for initialization.

Comment: sachin11 I agree. If you notice my example I pass it as a parameter (elements) and use it to limit the initialization loop. It would be nice to be able to just derive it from the pointer (like in my first non-working piece of code) but given how complicated that can get (see the article I linked above) it is much simpler to just pass it as a parameter.